# How to handle multiple copies on sale in an erc1155 marketplace contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, nft, markets

I am unsure how to create a marketplace contract for erc1155 nfts due to there being multiple copies on sale at the same time. What is the best way to implement this?
Code examples would be great.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How I would do it would be by using a mapping leading to the NFT's array of orders. Let's say:

```
struct Order {
    ...
}

mapping(address nftContract => mapping(uint256 nftId => Order[])) public ordersInfo;
```

Now, that's an ERC1155, so you still need a way to diferentiate an order from another, in other words make sure that when you want to buy X copies of the Y NFT from the frontend, they get picked up from the array, bought from the correct seller, etc...

Hope that helps